# Run code when both text boxes are empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# how do you display an error message if both text boxes are empty?  Is there a code example or validator that can be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

RequiredFieldValidator should do the job?
if you want to know more about validators then look here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/validation/aspnetvalidation.aspx

Comment: we cant use RFV,,the thing is that if both text boxes are empty only ,i will display error message

Comment: You could use a CustomValidator but i have only used one once so i cant tell you how it works..

Answer (score 0):

```
protected submit_click()
{
if((TextBox1.Text=="")||(TextBox2.Text==""))
  {
   print that error message
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks sevugarajan,,i thought we need some custom validator by using java script,, any way let me see whether it works or not

Answer (score 0):

```
if (TextBox1.Text == String.Empty && TextBox2.Text == String.Empty)
{
Label1.Text = "Your error message here";
}
else
{
//continue your logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CustomValidator gives you a callback method.  You can use it like any other validator, and write the following code in the [control name]_ServerValidate method:

```
args.IsValid = TextBox1.Text.Length > 0 && TextBox2.Text.Length > 0;
```

Comment: thank you rich,,for that we need to enable validation  to true in customvalidator

Answer (score 0):

Abstract to a scalable function:

```
private bool Validate(params TextBox[] boxes) {
    foreach (var box in boxes) 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(box.Text))
            return false;
    return true;            
}
```

then call with

```
if(Validate(TextBox1, TextBox2, ...)) { 
    /// Do the good stuff 
} else { 
    /// throw error 
}
```